# problems installing a DVC lower version [0.9.4]

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, dvc

I need to install an older version of DVC, namely 0.9.4, in a Python virtual environment.

I used the command:

```
pip install dvc==0.9.4
```

Everything seemed to work fine. However, when I try to run a `dvc pull` command, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\Scripts\dvc.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\dvc\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from dvc.cli import parse_args
  File "c:\users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\dvc\cli.py", line 8, in <module>
    from dvc.command.init import CmdInit
  File "c:\users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\dvc\command\init.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dvc.project import Project
  File "c:\users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\dvc\project.py", line 15, in <module>
    from dvc.cloud.data_cloud import DataCloud
  File "c:\users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\dvc\cloud\data_cloud.py", line 11, in <module>
    from dvc.cloud.gcp import DataCloudGCP
  File "c:\users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\dvc\cloud\gcp.py", line 4, in <module>
    from google.cloud import storage as gc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud'
```

When I print the dvc version, I see:

```
0.9.4+6bb66e.mod
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the remote storage is on Google Cloud based on that error, you may need to install the special `dvc[gs]` module instead, e.g.:

```
pip install dvc[gs]==0.9.4
```

See https://dvc.org/doc/install/linux#install-with-pip

BTW [DVC 1.x](https://github.com/iterative/dvc/releases?after=2.0.0a0) should be backward compatible with DVC 0.9 in case you want to try a newer version.

Also, try to migrate your project to DVC 2.x (latest as of now), here are some guidelines: https://dvc.org/blog/dvc-2-0-release#breaking-changes

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome the previous issue with:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
```